# How to find Equivalent resistance of solid regular bodies i-e solid sphere ,solid cube

Tags: resistance

How we can find the equivalent resistance of solid regular shaped bodies e.g solid sphere, solid cube

Comment: You could measure it.  Or use calculus.  (break it into little parts and add up the parallel and series pieces.  The sphere case sounds hard)

Answer (score 2):

Such problems are called "[boundary value problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_value_problem)", and they are solved using calculus. The key issue is to figure out what the distribution of the electric field within the solid is, and how this affects the movement of charges (current distribution). Since these two quantities affect each other, it requires differential equations to describe the relationship. How you apply the external field determines the "boundary conditions".

Such problems can become very complicated, especially in 3D space, unless you can exploit geometric symmetries to reduce the number of degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 0):

A solid cube or rectangle measured between the faces is easy because the current flow is uniform across the cross section.

There may be some closed-form way to calculate or estimate current flow in an L-shaped block or certain other irregular or curved section (for example section of a torus) but for practical purposes a DC conduction analysis using field solver software might be your best bet.